# Jquery remove class not working on a bc website

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I am trying to removeClass.addClass with jquery

```
<input class="cat_button botao-verde formulario-rodape" type="submit" value="Subscrever" id="catlistbutton" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("catalistbutton").click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("formulario-rodape").addClass("botaoclique");
  });
</script>
```

It is not working. It just adds the new class(no shadows) and the class to be removed that its a shadow effect remains in the code.

See it here at the bottom  of the page on the newsletter signup form, its the green button

http://ocozinheiroperfeito.businesscatalyst.com/

Comment: `$("catalistbutton")` is not a valid selector.... its `$("#catalistbutton")`.  If that fixes your problem, then I will add as an answer.

Comment: What's a "bc website", before christ ?

Comment: @GaryStorey If that is the problem, you should not answer the question. You should close it.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Thanks!  However, I don't believe I have permission to close it.

Comment: Bc is adobe business catalyst cms.I tryed to add the # and its still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selector is incorrect. Use `$("#catalistbutton")` to adress by id. Moreover I suggest putting DOM manipulating code inside the `$(document).ready();`

Comment: i just did that and its still the same.